# Is there a way to make this list for my online board game look better? for my terminals sake

Tags: python, list

so in my code, I have a line as such:

```
self.board= [[[]]*7] * 10
```

where and it produces this board to use in my game:

```
[[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], 
[], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []], [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]]
```

is there a way to get it to produce this instead:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []],
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []], 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

do note that I have removed the very first and last bracket, but this change of looks would make my code and terminal look a lot better.

Is there any way I can do this and also still use it later on?

Comment: don't do `self.board= [[[]]*7] * 10` as it duplicates the references of the sublists. Use `[[[] for _ in range(7)] for _ in range 10]`

Comment: then what you're seeing is a _representation_ of your matrix. Use a custom method to print the elements, you'll get better results

Comment: Simplest way seems for me:
    for k in self.board:
        print(k)

Comment: MatthiasL I ended up doing that, thanks